# unable to draw correctly in Gtk+3

Tags: gtk, drawing, pygtk, gtk3, drawingarea

I can draw in a single Gtk.DrawingArea, but when i try to do it for many, for example 50, ***i got some errors in drawing***.

[image]

Here is the code you need to check out:

```
def aggiorna(self, args=()):

        import random
        import time


        while True:
            for i in self.indirizzi_ip:
                self.r=random.randint(0,10)/10.0
                self.g=random.randint(0,10)/10.0
                self.b=random.randint(0,10)/10.0
                self.cpu_info[i]['drawing_area'].show() #the drawing happens here

            time.sleep(1)


    def __draw(self, widget, context): #connected to Gtk.DrawingArea.show()

        context.set_source_rgb(self.r, self.g, self.b) #random
        context.rectangle(0, 0, widget.get_allocated_width(), widget.get_allocated_height())
        context.fill()
```

1) why do i get errors in drawing?

2) why do Gtk.DrawingArea(s) change color ONLY when i update the window (for example i switch from a program to Gtk.DrawingArea window)?

3) why don't i get random colors for each Gtk.DrawingArea?

Answer (score 1):

1. cant help you on this
2. because it only changes color when Gtk.DrawingArea repainted itself ("draw" signal)
3. the r,g,b should be inside "draw" function. you did construct r,g,b but since it's outside the draw function, it did not change while area repainted.
4. why the sleep?

** edited **

sample code:

```
  ....
  win = Gtk.Window ()
  box = Gtk.Box ()
  self.square_list = []

  for square in range (10):
    self.darea = Gtk.DrawingArea ()
    self.set_size_request (50,50)
    self.square_list.append (self.darea)
    box.add (self.darea)

    #for each darea connect to separate "draw" signal
    self.darea.connect ("draw", self,_draw)

  aggiorna_button = Gtk.Button ('Aggiorna!!!') #sorry i use button
  box.add (aggiorna_button)
  aggiorna.button.connect ("clicked", self.aggiorna)

def _draw (self, widget, cr):
    r = random.randint (0,10)/10.0
    g = random.randint (0,10)/10.0
    b = random.randint (0,10)/10.0
    cr.set_source_rgb (r,g,b)
    cr.rectangle (0,0, widget.get_allocated_width(), widget.get_allocated_height())
    cr.fill ()

def aggiorna (self, widget):
   for darea in self.square_list:
        darea.queue_draw()
```

Comment: **2)** Remember that the "draw" signal is connected not to the top level Gtk.Window but to a Gtk.DrawingArea and i call ".show()" method every 1 sec. for each of them **4)** because if the drawing happened every 1 sec it could be easier for me to see the update. Thank you

Comment: 2). since Gtk.DrawingArea is a child of toplevel, when window re-draw itself, all the child must be drawn as well. otherwise, how your drawing area get allocated width and height? 4).got it. i'll think about it.... and ahhh...sorry, i though you creating 50 rectangle inside 1 drawing area...you did 50 drawing area in 1 window

Comment: edited the answer. i use button to refresh, u probably using timeout or something

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Now i have to solve the **1)**. This happens only when i scroll down/up the window